# How do I connect to an existing Access .mdb from Server Management Studio 17.2?

Tags: ms-access, ssms

I have just taken over an Access database and I have very limited Access experience and am much more comfortable in the Server Management Studio envrionment. How do I connect to the access database from SSMS as I can't seem to get this right (which may just be caused by my lack of MS Access experience). The Access Database is on a shared network drive, but only accessed by myself.

Comment: The correct tool to open an MS Access database in is MS Access. What happens when you double click the file? You can't really open an MS Access database in SSMS. (Yes you can create linked servers etc. but this isn't actually opening it)

Comment: What are you planning to do in SSMS? How is your database related to the MS SQL Server you're opening with SSMS? As @Nick.McDermaid said, often, the proper tool to use is just Access, even if you want to move your Access data into SSMS. I don't believe SSMS has proper syntax highlighting and such if you use Access as a linked server and want to write queries (ACE/JET SQL is a bit different from T-SQL).

Comment: Thanks guys, my problem did indeed just come down to limited access knowledge. I'm making do with the SQL tools in Access for the time being until this database is closed down.